# List and delete cached models from HuggingFace

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

When using a new model from HuggingFace, the necessary files are downloaded to a `.cache/huggingface/transformers` folder. However, these files are named using id numbers rather than with names referring to the type of model.

I wonder how I can list downloaded/existing models within python, and whether it is then possible to delete specified models using Python?